# Is sperm (spermatozoa) a bacteria?

Tags: microbiology

Is spermatozoa (ie human) technically considered bacteria? I've been told it is and I've been told it isn't. Would it meet the definition? If not what is sperm considered?

Comment: A sperm is not a bacterium - a sperm cell is an eukaryotic cell with a haploid set of chromosomes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sperm cell is a eukaryotic cell. All bacteria are prokaryotic. (doesn't necessarily mean all prokaryotic cells are bacteria). Whoever told you that it's technically considered a bacteria, must have used it as a figure of speech referring to it's characteristics.. example, the sperm cell has a flagellum, which some bacteria also have.

The sperm cell is neither technically nor literally a bacterium.

Answer (score 0):

Complement: it's not even a real being: it can't reproduce, it's almost not functioning (I'm not even sure than his DNA material is in a transcriptible form. Basically, it's a dedicated half-cell of a multicellular organism, frozen genetic packed content + a flagellum + mitochondria + enough energy to make it beat for a short duration. 
As such, we might even find it to share common things with the definition of virus :-)

Comment: If you try, you can even find commonalities with a parasite, but it all depends on definitions and perspective. Example, in order for it to "survive" it must break into an ovum and develop into a fetus, while a parasite also can rarely live without a host... It's all about changing an explanation to make it fit something, using the right words, you could even compare a sperm cell with a snake... Both use peristalsis to move.